# How do you password protect a server on a Mac running Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac, web-server, password-protected

I've seen tutorials on how to show a little box on the main page that you have to know the password to, but I want it where that textbox pops up and asks for a username and password, like the style used when you're trying to get into a router's settings.  I am just using the built in Apache that came with the Mac, I have a website set up, but can't figure out how to get the password protection.  Any links to information about this type of password protection would be good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question really belongs on [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com).com, but the answer is to use .[htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) auth files. Here's a [tutorial on Apache authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).